# Откуда отступы у блока и как их убрать?

Tags: css

```css
#main{
            width: 900px;
            height: 1000px;
            margin: 0 auto 0;
        }
        #section {
            width: 900px;
            height: 300px;
        }
        
        #one, #two, #tree {
            margin-top: 0px;
            display: inline-block;
            width:100%;
            height: 80px;
            background: red;

        }
```

```html
<body>
<div id="main">
    <section id="section"><!--
        --><div id="one"></div><!--
        --><div id ="two"></div><!--
        --><div id="tree"></div><!--
    --></section>
</div>  
</body>
```

Comment: display: block;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавляем `0` отступы у `html` и `body` для убирания бортовых отступов.

И делаем `display: block` у `#one, #two, #tree` для убирания межкомпонентных отступов.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#main {
  width: 900px;
  height: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto 0;
}

#section {
  width: 900px;
  height: 300px;
}

#one,
#two,
#tree {
  margin-top: 0px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <section id="section">
      <!--
        -->
      <div id="one"></div>
      <!--
        -->
      <div id="two"></div>
      <!--
        -->
      <div id="tree"></div>
      <!--
    -->
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Ну так все равно отступы есть

Comment: @Sinevik обновил ответ